# Interface design

Tags: feature-request, autocomplete

When I ask the question and someone makes a comment, I can start replying to that comment with "@" to direct reply to that person. Now when I start typing the nick of this person, the popup shows up with the complete nick. Or the complete nick shows up when I enter "@" symbol if the nick contains non-English letters.

Now when someone provides the answer to the question and I'm trying to reply, typing "@a" does not produce the pop-up with the full nick.

Is there a way to make a second scenario work the same way as first?

Comment: The owner of the post will be notified by default, there is no need to @-reply to the author.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, and if there are multiple comments and/or some discussion about the answer? "@" is a good way to reply directly.

Comment: @Igor if there are 3 or more users commenting (like on this meta post with this being the 3rd user), then it's possible to @-reply the author.

Answer (score 5):

> Now when someone provides the answer to the question and I'm trying to reply, typing "@a" does not produce the pop-up with the full nick.

That's by design, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020).

You do get an autocomplete box (including the answerer's username) when others beside you and the answerer have commented on their answer.

Comment: weird. No matter how many people are commenting on the answer, typing "@a", for example, does not produce autocompletion for me. That is if I understood the last paragraph correctly.

Comment: Which answer is that?

Comment: I don't remember exactly which one. I can try to dig it up though if needed. But does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, for example on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453588/266143) it works just fine.

Comment: I tried the linked question and it worked fine. Thank you. But then there is an inconsistency - on the comment I can post the the reply even for one person with autocompletion. I'm just surprised that it is not possible for the answer. OTOH since this is by design and, presumably, documented somewhere - it is not a bug then. ;-)